# Sampling data from a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random, simulation

Within a given simulation, I'm able to specify properties such as arrival times using a probability density function. However, I'm confused as to how the actual sampling is done from within the distribution.

For example, interarrival times may be *sampled* from an exponential distribution like so:
`exponential(1/11)` which leads to the following distribution:

[image: exponential]

How does the simulation sample data from within the distribution randomly, or rather how does the picking of random numbers within this PDF relate to the output?

My intuition says the graph indicates that there is a high probability that the random number sampled is within the 0-10 interval and then exponentially decreases.

Comment: There are many ways to draw *pseudo*-random samples from a continuous density function. In the case of the exponential distribution, one option is [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Textbooks on simulation--for example, *Simulation* by Sheldon Ross, or *Discrete Event Simulation* by George S. Fishman-- typically include a compendium of methods for sampling from various probability distributions.